# Why can't my Xbox One gaming rig allow installing Windows 8 software?

Tags: pc, xbox-one

This may be off-topic for this particular board but I couldn't find a better one and a question I had was bothering me.  I am looking at purchasing some new PC games to play but my gaming PC is outdated.  I don't want to drop another $1k +  to play games after just purchasing an Xbox One (gaming computer basically)

Why CAN'T I install Windows 8-compatible games on it?  Why restrict it to only Win8 apps?  Assuming that if Xbox One can run Windows 8 apps it has everything there necessary to install other software that they are just restricting content.

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows 8-compatible" games? Games that run in Windows 8 desktop (such as Battlefield 4) or as an app (such as Project Spark)?

Comment: Are you asking why you cant plays windows games on the console...?

Comment: "Why did they design it this way?" questions are off-topic.

Comment: As a note the selected reason it was marked off topic doesn't really cover the reason it was marked off topic.  I am not asking about game development I am asking why my gaming rig doesn't support x

Comment: "This includes speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative." - You're asking why Windows games don't work on an Xbone.  That's exactly what developer intent in regards to mechanics is.

Answer (score 5):

You can't run Windows games on an Xbox One because an Xbox One is not a Windows PC.  The Xbox One uses a custom CPU (based on AMD's Jaguar architecture) and a custom OS ("Xbox OS" with a custom kernel).

That said, both of these things are based on standards similar to that used for PCs - Jaguar is x86-based, and the underlying kernel of Xbox OS is a "custom Windows kernel."

Thus, Windows applications don't work because the system is customized from what a "stock" PC would use.  However, these customizations were done on purpose to differentiate it from a PC running Windows.  Why Microsoft made these choices is not something I can really answer.